# Room Tag type - REVIT API

Tags: revit-api

I have Room Tag family & its types as follows :

1. Room Tag Rec : Length X Width
2. Room Tag Rec : Width X Length
3. Room Tag Rec : Square

My question is, How to assign above room tag types in room tag in **REVIT 2018 API**

My existing tag name is Room Tag : *Room Tag With Area.*

I want set (Change) to Room Tag Rec : *Length X Width.*

There is no name set option.

Comment: Please give some context, sample code, etc. Also, please look at the API reference first: http://www.revitapidocs.com/

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the RoomTag-s from the document with the FilteredElementCollector class and you can use the BuiltInCategory, as a filter. At the end of the day a room tag type is just another type of FamilySymbol:

```
var roomTagInstance = doc.Create.NewRoomTag(args);
var roomTagTypes = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).
                       OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RoomTags).
                       Cast<FamilySymbol>();
roomTagInstance.ChangeTypeId(roomTagTypes.First(filter here))
```

Cheers